# How to find the matching element in a tiny array with unique elements as quickly as possible?

Tags: c, performance, set, compiler-optimization, simd

Inside the Erlang runtime system, persistent hashmaps are represented as hash-array-mapped-tries if they are big, and 'flatmaps' if they are small.

I recently was nerdsniped into looking for ways to optimize this. ^_^'

A flatmap has the following characteristics:

- There are at most 32 keys (and 32 values);
- They are stored unordered in a C array;
- There are no duplicate keys;
- Keys are unboxed: We can directly compare the two `uint64_t`'s together to check for a match.

The current implementation of this is:

```
uint64_t *original_flatmap_get(uint64_t *keys, uint64_t *vals, uint64_t key, uint64_t max_size) {
  uint64_t n = max_size;
  uint64_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (keys[i] == key) {
      return &vals[i];
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

*(Simplified from [the original](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/emulator/beam/erl_map.c#L210-L214))*

But this does not use above info at all.
I tried what happened if the compiler was made aware that

- there are at most 32 elements
- It's fine to return 'a' match rather than 'the first'; since the keys are unique there will only ever at most be a single match.

This lead to the following implementation:

```
uint64_t *latereturn_flatmap_get(uint64_t *keys, uint64_t *vals, uint64_t key, uint64_t max_size) {
  uint64_t n = min(max_size, 32);
  uint64_t i;

  uint64_t *res = NULL;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (keys[i] == key) {
      res = &vals[i];
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

[Looking at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7E3oEM4hr) we can see that Clang and GCC are able to vectorize and unroll the loop now.
[Benchmarking this](https://github.com/Qqwy/erlang-smallmap-get-benchmark) shows a 5-15% speedup.

---

However, now for the question: Is it possible to go further?

For instance, is it possible to indicate to the compiler somehow that all elements in the array will be unique which might enable even more optimizations?

Or are there maybe ways to manually write some SIMD instructions directly which are even faster?

Comment: Doesn't the first code example that you posted already stop at the first match?

Comment: Regarding SIMD optimization: Can you safely access values between `max_size` and 32? (If yes, would these be non-initialiized values?) Especially, if `max_size==0` can you access `*keys` at all? Can you make sure that `keys` is 16/32 byte aligned?

Comment: @Fra93 Correct, the original code stops at the first match. Curiously this is slower on modern architectures because it is not possible to vectorize or unroll the loop.

Comment: @chtz Unfortunately, no. The objects are heap-allocated and are not larger than is necessary (probably to fit more of them in cache at the same time). In the original code, there is an early `if(size == 0){ return NULL; }` before this particular loop. (So for this example, you can consider `size` to always be in the inclusive range 1..32.)

Not sure about alignment, but the answer is probably no. Great question!

Comment: Can you tweak how they're allocated to pad the allocation to a multiple of 16 bytes?  (x86-64 malloc implementations would probably do that anyway, since `alignof(max_align_t) == 16` means they wouldn't have a use for 8 bytes left at the end of an allocation.  And that malloc always returns 16-byte aligned memory.  But unfortunately the useful thing would be 32B alignment for AVX2, so aligned_alloc...  But that might waste more space in the allocator padding for alignment)

Comment: What are the *typical* sizes in common workloads?  Is it quite common for there to be a hit in the first 4 or even 2 elements, in which case tuning to keep that case fast is good (like Soonts' answer checking one SIMD vector at a time).  (Even if it means we don't scale as well for the size 32 or 31 cases, as long as scaling is still ok).

Comment: Note that GCC's auto-vectorization uses a large number of 32-byte vector constants.  A micro-benchmark won't reflect the cost of that extra cache footprint displacing more valuable stuff.  And it's not very good auto-vectorization unfortunately: 2x `vpblendvb` at each step, and the horizontal reduction at the ends looks really complicated.  (Perhaps because it doesn't know about the uniqueness property, so needs to make sure it takes the *last* match.  I haven't sorted out exactly what strategy it's using, but it seems to be calculating addresses in vectors at every step.)

Comment: I'd expect Soonts answer is a good balance between code-size (I-cache / uop-cache footprint) and branch predictability (same branching withing groups of 4) vs. max speed when the match is in element #31.

Comment: Note, your benchmark models a case where branches depending on `max_size` are perfectly predictable (benefiting solutions that might incur an extra misprediction in real usage), and the PRNG used is very slow: it's comparable to the function being benchmarked, making it impossible to interpret obtained speedup numbers.

Answer (score 5):

I’m not sure how faster it gonna get if at all, but here’s manually vectorized AVX2 version of your function.

```
uint64_t* flatmap_avx2( const uint64_t* keys, uint64_t* vals, uint64_t key, uint64_t max_size )
{
    const __m256i needle = _mm256_set1_epi64x( (int64_t)key );

    const uint64_t* const keysEnd = keys + max_size;
    const uint64_t* const keysEndAligned = keys + ( max_size / 4 ) * 4;

    for( ; keys < keysEndAligned; keys += 4, vals += 4 )
    {
        __m256i src = _mm256_loadu_si256( ( const __m256i* )keys );
        __m256i eq = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64( needle, src );
        uint32_t mask = (uint32_t)_mm256_movemask_epi8( eq );
        if( 0 == mask )
            continue;
        uint32_t byteIndex = _tzcnt_u32( mask );
        // The index is multiple of 8, in assembly all addresses expressed in bytes,
        // yet adding pointers in C adds elements not bytes, that's why casting
        return (uint64_t*)( ( (uint8_t*)vals ) + byteIndex );
    }

    for( ; keys < keysEnd; keys++, vals++ )
        if( *keys == key )
            return vals;

    return nullptr;
}
```

If you're building this with VC++, ideally add `#pragma loop( no_vector )` before the second `for` loop in the function.

Similarly, if you’re building with gcc or clang, ideally add `__attribute__((optimize("no-tree-vectorize")))` before the whole function.

Without these compiler-specific shenanigans, compilers may decide to automatically vectorize the second `for` loop with the remainder, inflating the code for no good reason.

Another performance-related thing. If you can, align your keys pointer by 32 bytes, will become slightly faster.

Comment: Could you add some comments to the code? What I am understanding is that you load 4 keys (256bits) into `src` then you duplicate four times the input and store it in `needle`, so that you can compare it and reduce it to a bit mask. You do this untill you find a one in the mask, then you pass to the next loop.  That loop is not vectorized right?

Comment: Only ICC knows how to vectorize search loops (trip-count not known before the first iteration).  Also, as long as `max_size >= 4`, you can end with a final unaligned vector that can overlap some elements you've previously looked at, if the total size isn't a multiple of 4.  (And you can use `vmovmskpd` to get qword indices instead of byte.  That might make it easier to use an integer offset instead of pointers, although for Intel you *want* the compiler to use an indexed addressing mode so `vpcmpeqq y,y,m` can stay micro-fused.  So maybe pointer subtraction at the end, `keys - key_initial`)

Comment: You might want to unroll to 2 compares per iteration, maybe blending (`vpblendd`) for `vmovmskps` to check for non-zeros.  Either pick it apart based on the position being odd vs. even, or redo qword (pd) movemasks separately.  (Or `vpor` / `vptest` to combine 2 results if we're going to redo a movemask anyway). Hmm, yeah picking it apart could work surprisingly well, like shift out the low bit, lea/cmov to conditionally add it back in at the top, perhaps.  But this depends on extra cleanup work being amortized over enough loop iterations to matter.  (Unfortunately vpacksswb is in-lane)

Comment: @Fra93 The first loop uses AVX2, it loads and compares 4 keys in parallel. For more details see intrinsics guide https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html The second `for` does the last 1-3 elements at the end of the input array.

Comment: @PeterCordes The OP only has 1-32 elements. If the distribution is uniform, we’ll get 1-3 keys with 3/32=9% probability, not great for branch prediction. It’s IMO similar with unrolling: good idea for long arrays, but for 1-32 I think the current relatively simple version is good enough because unrolling gonna cost instructions to decode and branches to mispredict.

Comment: Yeah, was just about to follow up and comment that with such a small max size, unrolling puts more of the work in the fallback more of the time, since it's not always going to be 32, that's just the max, and an early hit is likely.  With 16-byte vectors (SSE2 baseline) you might consider it, to make branching more predictable.  (A hit in any of the first 4 elements leaves the loop the same way, instead of just in groups of 2.)  2x `pmovmskpd` / `mask = (mask2 << 2) + mask1` (LEA) and bit-scan that.  (And re: size being below 4, yeah, in comments it seems over-read can't be guaranteed safe)

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea that goes this way:

The idea here is to get rid of the branch itself, which could, due to branch prediction on all newer (since 15 years) processors waste a lot of cycles and bump the performance of this function.

What I want is something that get executed on all keys, such that the result is mixed all together, but will still give the indication of where our flag is.

So the pseudo-idea-code is

```
res = 0 // Init to some neutral value
res = res <op> f(keys,key) // do an operation to mix the results with something that is function of the "search" method
```

Elaborating further:

- I know that when I do the bitwise `XOR` between a number and itself I get all zeros, while in all other cases I get a non zero value.
- I also know that `XOR`ing with 1 toggles a bit
- Processors have also an instruction to detect the number of ones, so I can use that to reduce every non-zero number to a 1, without using any `if`.
- The assumption is that running 32 operations every time is faster than checking the conditional code
- Another assumption is that bitwise operations are easily convertible into SIMD instructions and are faster on any processor.

Something that has these properties is the following:

```
1^reduce_or(keys[i]^key) << i 

keys[i]^key -> gives 0 if key matches, a random number otherwise
reduce_or   -> gives 0 if key matches, 1 otherwise
1^          -> gives 1 if key matches, 0 otherwise
<< i        -> moves the 1 to the bit position at which the key was matched
```

So the final idea:

```
res  = 0 
res = res | reduce_or(keys[0]^key) << 0; 
res = res | reduce_or(keys[1]^key) << 1; 
res = res | reduce_or(keys[2]^key) << 2; 
res = res | reduce_or(keys[3]^key) << 3; 
res = res | reduce_or(keys[4]^key) << 4; 
res = res | reduce_or(keys[5]^key) << 5; 
..; 
res = res | reduce_or(keys[31]^key) << 31;
```

After this pass we should have a number like `000000100000000`, and the one is at the index of which the key was found.

We still need to:

- Get an integer from the one-hot encoded number.
- Get the address.

To pass from the one hot encoded number to the position, it is just log2 of the result. However, this could be slow. I don't really have a solution for this. Maybe we can do, instead of shifting by `i`, multiply by `ì`, this will give us a 0 when the reduce_or is 0 and `i`, that is, the index already, when it is the right key.

```
 res  = 0 
 res = res + reduce_or(keys[0]^key) * 0; 
 res = res + reduce_or(keys[1]^key) * 1; 
 res = res + reduce_or(keys[2]^key) * 2; 
 res = res + reduce_or(keys[3]^key) * 3; 
 res = res + reduce_or(keys[4]^key) * 4; 
 res = res + reduce_or(keys[5]^key) * 5; 
 ..; 
 res = res + reduce_or(keys[31]^key) * 31;
```

We should test if doing the log is faster than doing sums and multiplications.

To get the address is just a matter of pointer arithmetic:

```
addr = vals+res
```

Anyway, this should give a branchless code :) I am curious to see if it will be faster or not!

Comment: This is an interesting idea. How do you suggest to tackle the cases in which the flatmap is smaller (and `keys` might not have 32 elements but only, say, 5)?

Comment: In C++ I would template the function with <N> number of elements and have a dynamic dispatcher that call the right statically compiled function. Again, this is possible only because we have at maximum 32 elements, so 32 functions. Is this a good idea? It might be but I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: I doubt it's a good idea to do an indirect branch on the size *before* touching the flatmap.  If that mispredicts, then no loads of the data are even in the pipeline yet.  vs. a branch mispredict *exiting* the loop after already touching the array.  If you loop over the whole array, that loop-branch doesn't depend on loaded data, just on the size, so a mispredict of it can be recovering while potential cache-miss loads are in flight, and the reduction work.  Also, 32 different copies of the loop is bad for I-cache footprint, especially uop-cache; the expected benefit is too small.  (@Qqwy)

Comment: There might be some benefit to branchlessly looping over the whole array if the same size is common but with different positions of the hit.  Instead of 1-hot and bit-scan, though, perhaps better to branchlessly update a seen-position (e.g. with x86 `cmov`, AArch64 `csel`).  Perhaps two such variables to hide latency.

Answer (score 2):

**At 32 elements max, the amount of CPU cycles to issue the entire loop is comparable to pipeline depth and branch misprediction penalty, so vectorized solutions need to be careful about poorly predictable branches in their prologues and epilogues.** A microbenchmark that repeatedly invokes the function with the same array size is prone to hiding this aspect, making a size-dependent branch perfectly predictable where it might not be in real usage.

I expect the following scalar loop to be preferable to vectorized solutions in actual usage:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define unlikely(cond) __builtin_expect((cond), 0)

uint64_t *
scal_flatmap_get(uint64_t *keys, uint64_t *vals, uint64_t key, uint64_t n)
{
    if (!n) return 0;

    uint64_t *last = &keys[n-1];
    for (uint64_t *k = keys; k < last; k += 2) {
#if defined(__aarch64__)
        // Show the compiler that k[1] can be loaded together with k[0]
        // so they can be combined in a load-pair (ldp) instruction
        uint64_t k1 = k[1], *pk1 = &k1;
#else
        uint64_t *pk1 = &k[1];
#endif
        if (unlikely(k[0] == key)) {
            // Prevent hoisting below computations in the loop
            asm("" : "+r"(k));
            return &vals[k-keys];
        }
        if (unlikely(*pk1 == key)) {
            asm("" : "+r"(k));
            return &vals[k+1-keys];
        }
    }
    return *last == key ? &vals[n-1] : 0;
}
```

On x86-64 the loop comprises the following instructions ([view on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bTvd3aGG9)):

```asm
.L6:
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rax], rdx
        je      .L11
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rax+8], rdx
        je      .L12
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rax, rcx
        jb      .L6
```

On popular x86 implementations one iteration of this loop can be issued in one cycle. Execution port(s) at which branch instructions can execute is the bottleneck, limiting it to between 1.5 and 3 cycles per two elements.

---

Alternatives that may look better in microbenchmarks:

#### The greedy switch

This one shines when the initial branch that depends on `n` is perfectly predictable.

```c
uint64_t *
switch_flatmap_get(uint64_t *keys, uint64_t *vals, uint64_t key, uint64_t n)
{
  switch (n-1) {
#define CASE(N) \
    case N: if (keys[N] == key) return &vals[N];
    CASE(31) CASE(30) CASE(29) CASE(28) CASE(27) CASE(26) CASE(25) CASE(24)
    CASE(23) CASE(22) CASE(21) CASE(20) CASE(19) CASE(18) CASE(17) CASE(16)
    CASE(15) CASE(14) CASE(13) CASE(12) CASE(11) CASE(10) CASE(9)  CASE(8)
    CASE(7)  CASE(6)  CASE(5)  CASE(4)  CASE(3)  CASE(2)  CASE(1)  CASE(0)
    default: return 0;
  }
}
```

#### GCC generic vectors showcase

Same source compiles to reasonable AVX and ARMv8 NEON assembly ([view on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6fqhr8o61)):

```c
// Poor man's 'branchless select'
static uintptr_t sel(int cond, uintptr_t p, uintptr_t q)
{
  asm("" : "+r"(p), "+r"(q));
  q = cond ? p : q;
  asm("" : "+r"(p), "+r"(q));
  return q;
}

uint64_t *
vec_flatmap_get(uint64_t *keys, uint64_t *vals, uint64_t key, uint64_t n)
{
  if (!n) return 0;

  uintptr_t res = sel(keys[n-1] == key, (uintptr_t)&vals[n-1],  0);

  if (n == 1) return (void *)res;

  res = sel(keys[(n|1)-2] == key, (uintptr_t)&vals[(n|1)-2], res);
  res = sel(keys[(n|1)-3] == key, (uintptr_t)&vals[(n|1)-3], res);

  typedef uint64_t u64v2 __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
  typedef u64v2 u64v2_u  __attribute__((aligned(8),may_alias));

  u64v2_u *vkeys = (void *)keys;
  u64v2 vvals01 = { 0,  8  }; vvals01 += (uintptr_t)vals;
  u64v2 vvals23 = { 16, 24 }; vvals23 += (uintptr_t)vals;
  u64v2 vkey = { key, key };
  u64v2 vres = { 0 };

  for (; vkeys != (void*)&keys[n&-4]; vkeys += 2) {
    u64v2 v01 = vkeys[0] == vkey, v23 = vkeys[1] == vkey;
    vres |= vvals01 & v01;
    vres |= vvals23 & v23;
    vvals01 += 32;
    vvals23 += 32;
  }

  res |= vres[0] | vres[1];

  return (void *)res;
}
```

Comment: On AMD CPUs, `vpblendvb` would be more efficient than `vpand` / `vpor`; Zen2 and later run it as a single uop.  (On Intel CPUs, though, it's at least 2 uops, and 3 on Alder Lake.  But only 1 for the non-VEX legacy SSE4.1 version on SKL and later.)  I forget if GNU C native vectors portably expose that operation, but it's too bad neither GCC nor Clang optimize your code to that even with `-march=znver3` where it has 2/clock throughput.  It might also be good to use 256-bit vectors if available, although it makes the horizontal reduction more expensive (an extra shuffle/OR step).

Comment: @PeterCordes My code has `a|b&c` which is not equivalent to a blend; `a&~c|b&c` would be (provided the compiler manages to prove that each byte in `c` is either 0 or 0xFF. GCC generic vectors expose blend when translating `cond ? a : b` in C++ mode (but not C): https://godbolt.org/z/aTozK4aeP

Comment: Oh right, that's only equivalent under the assumption that there's only one match, which the compiler doesn't know.  I'd guess the AArch64 `bit` select instruction is efficient on most implementations, since they didn't make it weird (4 operands) like Intel did for the AVX version of `vpblendvb` :/  (`vpternlogd` is efficient on Intel CPUs with AVX512)

Comment: @PeterCordes Regarding 256-bit vectors, I think the problem is not so much the extra shuffle/or, but rather how to avoid further growth of scalar prologue/epilogue. My solution was to run matching from both sides, at the cost of redundant work when the two vectors meet in the middle: https://godbolt.org/z/sxfY8hseP

Comment: I was thinking of just dropping the unroll, and doing one compare per iteration if 32-byte vectors were available.  So your existing code (which enter the loop when there are 4 or more elements to check) would just work.  But yeah, letting vectors overlap can be a good strategy to simplify branching, neat idea.